# Mustard substitute

Tags: substitutions, mustard

My husband just found out he's allergic to mustard.  Are there any substitutes for it? It's a  staples in my kitchen and he loves it.

---

Edit for clarification (was in the original question):
Husband is also allergic to horseradish and egg whites, so substituting horseradish for mustard is not an option.

Comment: The substitute you use will depend on what you're using it in, I would think...

Comment: I'm going to edit this down to just ask about mustard since that's what's in the title. Please do ask about the others too though!

Comment: For the mustard, I might add a shot of vinegar to make up for the lack of acid that's generally in most prepared mustard (especially if you're replacing dijon mustard).  Any other flavorings would likely vary based on the dish, as Catija mentioned.  And in the some cases, the vinegar might be in something else (eg, using mayo for a sandwich ... but you have to make sure it's a mayo that doesn't use mustard as an emulsifier)

Comment: you could use very fress watercress in some recipes.

Comment: Pickled and pureed hot radish paste, with plenty of vinegar and some turmeric?

Answer (score 3):

Fermented vegetables can often provide the pungent, salty kick that is often desired from mustard. If he is not allergic to cabbage (which is a member of the same family, *brassica*), sauerkraut may be a good option. Similarly, other members of the *brassica* family, such as broccoli and collard greens, retain a similar bite, particularly when raw. You might try making a collard green pesto.

Outside the brassica family, tamarinds can deliver a pungent, sour flavor that complements many different kinds of foods. Tamarind is a signature ingredient in many sauces and chutneys, particularly for meat. You could try [making your own A1 sauce](https://twodogsinthekitchen.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/homemade-a-1-steak-sauce/) while leaving out the mustard.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that even closely resembles mustard that I can think of would be Horseradish and real wasabi.

Comment: Unfortunately horseradish is also something he's allergic to, but that got edited out of the question.

Comment: Sometimes wasabi is *not* stretched with horseradish, quite often it *is*, so read the labels carefully.